Why is iter_const_reference_t not simply using std::add_const_t?
iterator_const_reference_t is implemented as follows:
template<std::indirectly_readable T>
using iter_const_reference_t = std::common_reference_t<const std::iter_value_t<T> &&,
                                                       std::iter_reference_t<T>>;

But why? Why isn't it simply: std::add_const_t<std::iter_reference_t<T>>?

std::add_const_t<T &> is just T &, you need to remove the reference before applying it. But that probably isn't good enough either, because iter_reference_t doesn't have to be an actual reference.

add_const_t<int&> will still be int&, which is not a const reference. You probably mean const iter_value_t<T>& but that might lead to dangling issues.
The formula in your question comes from range/v3 which has been around for years and can handle almost all cases including proxy references.
For example, the reference of zip_view's iterator, namely tuple<int&, int&>, cannot be made a const reference just by adding a top-level const-qualifier.
In this case, we can apply common_reference's specialization for tuple to produce the correct reference type i.e. tuple<const int&, const int&>, that's why the formula of iter_const_reference_t has the common_reference part.
